# Log4j2 isn't rolling files like it did in the first revision, Am I missing something in the new config layout?

Tags: java, log4j2, rollingfileappender

There are two problems I am encountering when using log4j2 and the RollingFile appender.
The first is that if there are no existing archived files than it always puts the earliest date possible as the file name instead of the file creation date or the touch date.
The second issue happens mostly during testing because I start and stop my code a lot.  Whenever I stop/start the server it moves the current log to archive instead of appending to the current log.  There are no special steps to create this, just have one current log from today and start the program.

I've tried manually setting the TimeBaseTriggerPolicy, the RollingFile append property and changing the file pattern several times but nothing seems to fix this. I have gone over the log4j2 manual since the items are different than in the first version.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="runningLog"
            filename="./logs/FooIncoming.log"
            filePattern="./logs/FooIncoming-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
            ignoreExceptions="false"
            append="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] %x [%t] [%c{2}] [%m]%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>
...
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.foo.bar"  additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="runningLog" level="debug" />
            <AppenderRef ref="errorLog" level="error" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="error" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="research_logger" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RESEARCH" level="all"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="runningLog"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

As info the below replacement is a work around I found to work but it still seems odd I can't do it the way the api documents said I could.

```
<Policies>
   <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
</Policies>
<DefaultRolloverStrategy>
   <Delete basePath="./logs/" maxDepth="1">
      <IfFileName glob="FooIncoming-??????????.log" />
      <IfLastModified age="10d" />
   </Delete>
</DefaultRolloverStrategy>
```